# Clojurescript duplicate extern input error

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, google-closure-compiler, screeps

I am working on my first "real" clojurescript project and have run into a problem.

The goal is to upload the resulting javascript to https://screeps.com for the purpose of playing that game.

I am using a fork of someone's externs/general library found at [screeps-beans commit 5930152](https://github.com/archlisp/screeps-beans/tree/59301525b15621572447f00b714c1105ae13cd7f). This fork's scripts/watch works fine to build it and appears to generate the appropriate javascript as far as I can tell.

I created [my-screeps commit 181a9da5](https://gitlab.com/mordocai/my-screeps/tree/181a9da5795d18821cb251fecaa6a82cf38df2ba) which uses lein checkouts to pull in screeps-beans. It currently just tries to println to the console (the plan would be for it to eventually contain all the logic for my game AI that isn't general enough to go into screeps-beans).

I used https://github.com/swannodette/mies to generate scripts/ and I've run into the duplicate extern input issue.

If I use scripts/build it seems to work fine but as far as I can tell is not going to work very well for https://screeps.com.

If I use scripts/release I get:

```
➜  my-screeps git:(clojurescript) ✗ scripts/release 
Building ...
Analyzing jar:file:/home/myusername/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/1.9.229/clojurescript-1.9.229.jar!/cljs/core.cljs
Analyzing src/my_screeps/core.cljs
Applying optimizations :advanced to 14 sources
Sep 08, 2016 1:08:18 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: ERROR - Duplicate extern input: /home/myusername/git_repos/screeps-beans/resources/screeps/externs/screeps.ext.js

Sep 08, 2016 1:08:18 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager printSummary
WARNING: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
ERROR: JSC_DUPLICATE_EXTERN_INPUT. Duplicate extern input: /home/myusername/git_repos/screeps-beans/resources/screeps/externs/screeps.ext.js at (unknown source) line (unknown line) : (unknown column)
... done. Elapsed 3.692992138 seconds
```

The release script calls the clojurescript compiler using

```
(require '[cljs.build.api :as b])

(println "Building ...")

(let [start (System/nanoTime)]
  (b/build "src"
           {:output-to "release/main.js"
            :output-dir "release"
            :optimizations :advanced
            :verbose true})
  (println "... done. Elapsed" (/ (- (System/nanoTime) start) 1e9) "seconds"))
```

I imagine I have a typo or other similar misunderstanding somewhere in either screeps-beans or my-screeps, but I am at a loss.

Edit:

I have found that I can get this working by putting the extern in my-screeps instead of screeps-beans. You can see what this looks like by taking a look at [screeps-beans commit 6b80c77](https://github.com/archlisp/screeps-beans/commit/6b80c772d35f95b443126fe6d6a9dca81f303d2a) and [my-screeps commit 636ab847](https://gitlab.com/mordocai/my-screeps/commit/636ab84782cd9bcc71c8e5f5f9d19729a07e1a80). Basically I moved the resources directory and the src/deps.cljs to my-screeps.

I consider this a workaround and not an actual answer.